# How Do I Write An Rspec Test for A Link Which Includes a Locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, internationalization, rspec-rails, i18n-gem

I am writing tests with RSpec 2 for a Ruby on Rails 4.0.5 application with localization.  I am using examples from Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.  I am attempting to rewrite tests where a logged in person is trying to access pages for a different person.  The examples from the tutorial do not include localization.

```
describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

  describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
    before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
    before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
  end
end
```

I have the routes in my application where the links look like http://example.con/locale instead of http://example.con/?locale=locale.

My tests are within a loop.

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|

  subject { page }

  all my tests...........

end
```

Here is my attempt to rewrite my tests using local_root_path:

```
describe "as wrong member" do

  let(:member) { FactoryGirl.create(:member) }
  let(:wrong_member) { FactoryGirl.create(:member, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { login member, no_capybara: true }

  describe "submitting a GET request to the Members#edit action" do
    before { get edit_member_path(wrong_member, locale: locale) }
    specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title("#{wrong_member.first_name} #{wrong_member.last_name}")) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(locale_root_path) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Members#update action" do
    before { patch member_path(wrong_member, locale: locale) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(locale_root_path) }
  end

end
```

I get the following errors when I run my tests.

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication authorization as wrong member submitting a GET request to the Members#edit action 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(locale_root_path) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/en> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/?locale=en>.
       Expected "http://www.example.com/en" to be === "http://www.example.com/?locale=en".
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:101:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization as wrong member submitting a PATCH request to the Members#update action 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(locale_root_path) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/en> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/?locale=en>.
       Expected "http://www.example.com/en" to be === "http://www.example.com/?locale=en".
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:106:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have found some examples with this error but none that relate to the formatting of an I18 URL.

Any help will be appreciated.  I will keep searching.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I have managed to solve by following advice from the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:--Redirect-with-locale-after-authentication-failure). I presume the problem is related to the way in which Devise calls `default_url_options` but I'm not sure.

> Set your locale & Make your default_url_options a class method in your ApplicationController

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end

def self.default_url_options(options={})
  options.merge({ :locale => I18n.locale })
end
```